# Flask, Apache, mod_wsgi: unable to save file on server side

Tags: python, apache, file, file-upload, flask

From the client side I am sending an image via post from `form enctype=multipart/form-data`, and on the server side I am saving it to a directory. All of this works locally on my computer and running flask directly with `python app.py`.

Here is my reference for setting up file saving:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/

On the actual production server, I am running it with Apache and mod_wsgi, which I set up according to this website:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/

For directory permissions I have tried`chown -R 777` and `chown -R www-data:www-data` where the relevant Apache code for users looks like this: `WSGIDaemonProcess app user=www-data group=www-data threads=5`.

However, after all of this I am still not able to get the file to save. I just get a 500 HTTP error back at the point where it tries to save the file.

Here is the relevant Flask code:

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/images/'
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@app.route('/upload_ocr_images', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_images():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.files.getlist("images[]")
        for file in files:
            if allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

At this point I am wondering if there is something I need to be setting on the Apache side of things.

Comment: Looks like it is a path issue. Can take care of it with absolute path or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12081789/pythons-working-directory-when-running-with-wsgi-and-apache

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Youre using `/uploads` as your path.
That means you're trying to upload to a directory named `/uploads` at root level of your filesystem.

This is usually wrong and normally it's the error.

If you've the `uploads` folder **under** your flask application file structure, then you should create the path using `app.root_path` which holds the absolute application path.

Something like

```
file.save(os.path.join(app.root_path, '/uploads', filename))
```